# Rust reference and dereferencing

Tags: rust

Here is a short snippet of a Rust code with which I'm trying to understand Rust referencing and dereferencing :

```
fn main() {
    let mut i: i32 = 1;
    println!("i in main: {}", i);
    increment(&mut i);
    println!("i in main: {}", i);

    let mut a = String::from("ABCD");
    println!("a in main: {}", a);
    addchr(&mut a);
    println!("a in main: {}", a);
}

pub fn increment(i: &mut i32) {
    *i += 1;
    println!("i in increment: {}", *i);
}

pub fn addchr(s: &mut String) {
    s.push('a');
    println!("a in addchr: {}", s);
}
```

In the case of the integer, the function receiving the reference needs to dereference it (*i) but not in the case of a String (dereferencing seems to be "automatic").

What makes this difference ? Is it just regarding where the memory is allocated (stack or heap) ?

Comment: [When looking up a method call, the receiver may be automatically dereferenced or borrowed in order to call a method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html)

Comment: If I don't dereference i with *i, I get a compilation error. error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `&mut i32`
  --> src\main.rs:14:5
   |
14 |     i += 1;
   |     -^^^^^
   |     |
   |     cannot use `+=` on type `&mut i32`
   |
help: `+=` can be used on `i32` if you dereference the left-hand side
   |
14 |     *i += 1;
   |     +

Comment: @Masklinn while this is true, in this specific case `String::push` takes a `&mut String` and `s: &mut String`, so no automatic deref is performed.

Answer (score 5):

This is because of the method call syntax. Each method has a "receiver" argument (the one called `self` and its variations). This means that `my_string.push(...)` is basically syntactic sugar for* `String::push(&mut my_string, ...)` because the receiver of the [`push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push) method is `&mut self`.

In your example, `s: &mut String` and so this method call desugaring doesn't need any extra reference/dereference operation.

For `i32` though, the add assign operator acts on `mut i32` directly (note: no reference), therefore you need to dereference `&mut i32` with the `*` operator. This is only because you're using the `+=` operator directly though, if you were to instead use the [`AddAssign::add_assign`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html) method that's defined on `i32` you [wouldn't need to dereference either](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=044ebd035df90a701ff4d9b598093849).

---

* I don't actually know whether this syntactic sugar is exactly how the compiler does this, but I believe whatever it does is equivalent to this, since [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html?highlight=method#defining-methods) would remove any unnecessary refs introduced by this desugaring.